# How to convert xml data into a csv file?

Tags: xml, csv

I have the following data in xml format. Now, I need to extract data from the headers 'Expression Field 1', 'X Gender', 'Entrant Age', etc. into a csv file. I have written the following code but it doesn't work. Please help. When I try the following code, I get the error ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag''

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import pandas as pd

cols = ["EXPRESSION_FIELD_1", "XGENDER", "ENTRANT-AGE", "CATEGORY2-NUM__SNZ", "XCATEGORY1", "RESULT-TIME-MILLISECONDS","FINA-POINTS__SNZ"]
rows = []

# Parsing the XML file
xmlparse = Xet.parse('sample.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()

for i in root:
    name = i.find("EXPRESSION_FIELD_1").tag
    gender = i.find("XGENDER").tag
    age = i.find("ENTRANT-AGE").tag
    category = i.find("CATEGORY2-NUM__SNZ").tag
    result = i.find("XCATEGORY1").tag
  
    rows.append({"name": name,
                 "gender": gender,
                 "age": age,
                 "category": category,
                 "result": result})
  
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
  
# Writing dataframe to csv
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<TableData>
    <Fields>
        <Field align="" field="FRAGMENT_DISPLAY.SPLITS" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="Expander" name="FRAGMENT_DISPLAY-SPLITS" showInExpander="true" sortable="true" source="tableColumn" type="string" width=""/>
        <Field align="" field="EXPRESSION_FIELD_1" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="Name " name="EXPRESSION_FIELD_1" showInExpander="false" sortable="false" source="tableColumn" type="string" width="130"/>
        <Field align="" field="XGENDER" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="Gender" name="XGENDER" showInExpander="false" sortable="true" source="tableColumn" type="string" width="50"/>
        <Field align="" field="ENTRANT.AGE" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="Age" name="ENTRANT-AGE" showInExpander="false" sortable="true" source="tableColumn" type="int" width="35"/>
        <Field align="" field="CATEGORY2.NUM$$SNZ" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="Distance" name="CATEGORY2-NUM__SNZ" showInExpander="false" sortable="true" source="tableColumn" type="int" width="70"/>
        <Field align="" field="XCATEGORY1" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="Stroke" name="XCATEGORY1" showInExpander="false" sortable="true" source="tableColumn" type="string" width="70"/>
        <Field align="right" field="RESULT.TIME.MILLISECONDS" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="Time " name="RESULT-TIME-MILLISECONDS" showInExpander="false" sortable="true" source="tableColumn" type="int" width="70"/>
        <Field align="right" field="FINA.POINTS$$SNZ" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="FINA Points" name="FINA-POINTS__SNZ" showInExpander="false" sortable="true" source="tableColumn" type="string" width="85"/>
        <Field align="right" field="FINA.YEAR$$SNZ" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="Points Year" name="FINA-YEAR__SNZ" showInExpander="false" sortable="true" source="tableColumn" type="string" width="80"/>
        <Field align="right" field="$DATE$COMP.DATE" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="Date" name="_DATE_COMP-DATE" showInExpander="false" sortable="true" source="tableColumn" type="string" width="70"/>
        <Field align="" field="XEVENT.CODE" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="Meet" name="XEVENT-CODE" showInExpander="false" sortable="true" source="tableColumn" type="string" width="190"/>
        <Field align="" field="PARAMETER1" hasEmailLink="false" hasHyperlink="false" hidden="false" id="" label="Course" name="PARAMETER1" showInExpander="false" sortable="true" source="tableColumn" type="string" width="50"/>
        <Field field="MEMBER.FORE1" name="MEMBER-FORE1" type="string"/>
        <Field field="MEMBER.SURNAME" name="MEMBER-SURNAME" type="string"/>
        <Field field="XCATEGORY2" name="XCATEGORY2" type="string"/>
        <Field field="TIME$$SNZ" name="TIME__SNZ" type="string"/>
    </Fields>
    <TotalRows>77910</TotalRows>
    <StartRowIndex>21</StartRowIndex>
    <EndRowIndex>41</EndRowIndex>
    <RowCount>20</RowCount>
    <Rows>
        <Row>
            <MEMBER-FORE1>Ieuan</MEMBER-FORE1>
            <MEMBER-SURNAME>Edwards</MEMBER-SURNAME>
            <XCATEGORY2>100 metre</XCATEGORY2>
            <TIME__SNZ>1:30.23</TIME__SNZ>
            <FRAGMENT_DISPLAY-SPLITS type="string">&lt;!-- Start Fragment DISPLAY.SPLITS--&gt;&lt;!-- Time Taken 16 Milliseconds--&gt;&lt;apt_fragment_ms.comp.results_display.splits&gt;&lt;div class="test-message" style="display:none"&gt;Public&lt;/div&gt;&lt;!-- Start Display Process B:MS.CMS.BUILD.COMP.RESULTS.SPLITS,PUBLISHED,6--&gt;&lt;!-- Time Taken 0 Milliseconds--&gt;&lt;table border="1" &gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Split Distance&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style="width:50px" align="right"&gt;50&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style="width:50px" align="right"&gt;100&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Cumulative&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td  align="right"&gt;42.53&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td  align="right"&gt;1:30.23&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Individual&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td  align="right"&gt;42.53&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td  align="right"&gt;47.70&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;!-- End Display Process B:MS.CMS.BUILD.COMP.RESULTS.SPLITS,PUBLISHED,6--&gt;&lt;div class="test-message" style="display:none"&gt;&lt;div class="apt-form-item"&gt;&lt;label&gt;Staff Site&lt;/label&gt;&lt;span class="output"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="apt-form-item"&gt;&lt;label&gt;Key&lt;/label&gt;&lt;span class="output"&gt;004837*I*1319&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="apt-form-item"&gt;&lt;label&gt;Stage&lt;/label&gt;&lt;span class="output"&gt;P&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="apt-form-item"&gt;&lt;label&gt;Heat&lt;/label&gt;&lt;span class="output"&gt;1&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;style&gt;&#13;/*&lt;![CDATA[*/.fields table {border:0 none;}.splits td {background-color:pink;}/*]]&gt;*/&#13;&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/apt_fragment_ms.comp.results_display.splits&gt;&lt;!-- End Fragment DISPLAY.SPLITS--&gt;</FRAGMENT_DISPLAY-SPLITS>
            <EXPRESSION_FIELD_1>Ieuan Edwards</EXPRESSION_FIELD_1>
            <XGENDER type="string">Male</XGENDER>
            <ENTRANT-AGE type="int">18</ENTRANT-AGE>
            <CATEGORY2-NUM__SNZ type="int">100 metre</CATEGORY2-NUM__SNZ>
            <XCATEGORY1 type="string">Breaststroke</XCATEGORY1>
            <RESULT-TIME-MILLISECONDS type="int">1:30.23</RESULT-TIME-MILLISECONDS>
            <FINA-POINTS__SNZ type="string">250</FINA-POINTS__SNZ>
            <FINA-YEAR__SNZ type="string">2021</FINA-YEAR__SNZ>
            <_DATE_COMP-DATE type="string">10/04/2021</_DATE_COMP-DATE>
            <XEVENT-CODE type="string">2021 Aon New Zealand Swimming Championships</XEVENT-CODE>
            <PARAMETER1 type="string">L</PARAMETER1>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <MEMBER-FORE1>Sophie</MEMBER-FORE1>
            <MEMBER-SURNAME>Irving</MEMBER-SURNAME>
            <XCATEGORY2>50 metre</XCATEGORY2>
            <TIME__SNZ>29.73</TIME__SNZ>
            <FRAGMENT_DISPLAY-SPLITS type="string">&lt;!-- Start Fragment DISPLAY.SPLITS--&gt;&lt;!-- Time Taken 16 Milliseconds--&gt;&lt;apt_fragment_ms.comp.results_display.splits&gt;&lt;div class="test-message" style="display:none"&gt;Public&lt;/div&gt;&lt;!-- Start Display Process B:MS.CMS.BUILD.COMP.RESULTS.SPLITS,PUBLISHED,6--&gt;&lt;!-- Time Taken 0 Milliseconds--&gt;&lt;table border="1" &gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Split Distance&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td style="width:50px" align="right"&gt;50&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Cumulative&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td  align="right"&gt;29.73&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Individual&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td  align="right"&gt;29.73&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;!-- End Display Process B:MS.CMS.BUILD.COMP.RESULTS.SPLITS,PUBLISHED,6--&gt;&lt;div class="test-message" style="display:none"&gt;&lt;div class="apt-form-item"&gt;&lt;label&gt;Staff Site&lt;/label&gt;&lt;span class="output"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="apt-form-item"&gt;&lt;label&gt;Key&lt;/label&gt;&lt;span class="output"&gt;004837*I*131&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="apt-form-item"&gt;&lt;label&gt;Stage&lt;/label&gt;&lt;span class="output"&gt;P&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="apt-form-item"&gt;&lt;label&gt;Heat&lt;/label&gt;&lt;span class="output"&gt;2&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;style&gt;&#13;/*&lt;![CDATA[*/.fields table {border:0 none;}.splits td {background-color:pink;}/*]]&gt;*/&#13;&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/apt_fragment_ms.comp.results_display.splits&gt;&lt;!-- End Fragment DISPLAY.SPLITS--&gt;</FRAGMENT_DISPLAY-SPLITS>
            <EXPRESSION_FIELD_1>Sophie Irving</EXPRESSION_FIELD_1>
            <XGENDER type="string">Female</XGENDER>
            <ENTRANT-AGE type="int">18</ENTRANT-AGE>
            <CATEGORY2-NUM__SNZ type="int">50 metre</CATEGORY2-NUM__SNZ>
            <XCATEGORY1 type="string">Butterfly</XCATEGORY1>
            <RESULT-TIME-MILLISECONDS type="int">29.73</RESULT-TIME-MILLISECONDS>
            <FINA-POINTS__SNZ type="string">554</FINA-POINTS__SNZ>
            <FINA-YEAR__SNZ type="string">2021</FINA-YEAR__SNZ>
            <_DATE_COMP-DATE type="string">10/04/2021</_DATE_COMP-DATE>
            <XEVENT-CODE type="string">2021 Aon New Zealand Swimming Championships</XEVENT-CODE>
            <PARAMETER1 type="string">L</PARAMETER1>
        </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. And, btw, to write to csv you don't really need to go through pandas:

```
data = []
rows = root.findall('.//Row')
for i in rows:   
    name = i.find(".//EXPRESSION_FIELD_1").text
    gender = i.find(".//XGENDER").text
    age = i.find(".//ENTRANT-AGE").text
    category = i.find(".//CATEGORY2-NUM__SNZ").text
    result = i.find(".//XCATEGORY1").text
    data.append([name,gender,age,category,result])

cols = ["EXPRESSION_FIELD_1", "XGENDER", "ENTRANT-AGE", "CATEGORY2-NUM__SNZ", "XCATEGORY1"]

#now just write to csv
with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(cols)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Jack. When I use this code, I get a blank csv file with only the headers. What could be the reason, Jack?

Comment: @SanjayFuloria I can't tell the reason - the answer is based on the xml in your question; that xml had to be fixed (it's not well formed) and it probably is not representative of the actual xml in `sample.xml` you are using. See if you get a different result if you try to load into pandas first and then save to csv. You'll have to feel your way around and fit  the answer to your actual file.

Comment: Right, Jack. Thanks. Even with pandas, I am getting the same result. The formatting of xml could be a problem. I will check.

Comment: Thank you very much, @JackFleeting. It worked. I used BBEdit to save the xml and then used that file and your code worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code with @JackFleeting's help. I used BBEdit to save the xml file first and used it. MS Word didn't work for this.

```
#Importing the required libraries
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

#Parsing the xml file
tree = ET.parse("sample.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

#Creating an array and looping through the document to find headers
data = []
rows = root.findall('.//Row')
for i in rows:   
    name = i.find(".//EXPRESSION_FIELD_1").text
    gender = i.find(".//XGENDER").text
    age = i.find(".//ENTRANT-AGE").text
    category = i.find(".//CATEGORY2-NUM__SNZ").text
    result = i.find(".//XCATEGORY1").text
    data.append([name,gender,age,category,result])

#Creating columns
    cols = ["EXPRESSION_FIELD_1", "XGENDER", "ENTRANT-AGE", "CATEGORY2-NUM__SNZ", "XCATEGORY1"]

#now just write to csv
with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(cols)
    writer.writerows(data)
```